# Why should one delete sstate-cache when deleting tmp in Yocto build?

Tags: build, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

The section [5.2.7. build/tmp/](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#structure-build-tmp) of the Yocto Reference Manual says:

> As a last resort, to clean up a build and start it from scratch (other than the downloads), you can remove everything in the `tmp` directory or get rid of the directory completely. If you do, you should also completely remove the `build/sstate-cache` directory.

Does this mean that if one deletes the `tmp`, they should *always* delete `sstate-cache` as well and things break if they don't, or is it just a confusing formulation meaning it won't really be from scratch if the `sstate-cache` is still there?

And if it is the former, what is the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a confusing formulation.  If you want to do a build from absolute clean then you need to wipe sstate-cache as otherwise it won't be from scratch. You can delete tmp as much as you want and keep the sstate (personally my tmp is in a tmpfs so gets emptied several times a day, but the sstate-cache is years old).